# I want to develop Ethereum miner? what do I need?

Tags: mining

I want to develop Ethereum miner .

do I need to use  "Ethereum" and "geth" ?

can I do it with out Ethereum lab ?

as  I understand miner should has those task :

1-connect to pool
2-getting hashing.
3-calculate hashing with  Gpu .
4.sending back the information to pool again .
5-getting rewards and send it to wallet.

is this what do I need to build miner ?

is it hard or easy ?

Comment: If you have previously writtend mining software it should be easy.